# Is tevel dough muktzah on yom tov?

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, bread, separating-challah, muktzeh

If one baked bread on yom tov in Eretz Yisroel (from dough kneaded prior to Yom Tov) and relized when the bread was still in the oven that he forgot to take off challah, must the bread then be considered muktzah? If indeed it is muktzah, would one have to leave it in the oven the entire time even until it burns or could one save it and take it out?

Comment: This seems to involve a few questions. Perhaps some of them can be restated as follows (if you have something else in mind, please clarify): (1.) Since the bread is not permissible in its current state, is it muktzah? (2.) If muktzah, can the bread be moved anyway (e.g. via *kil'achar yad*)? (3.) If so, can it be saved under the principle of protecting one's property on Yom Tov, or it is an act of *hachanah* to save the bread? Alternatively: (4.) In the absence of any mitigating mechanism like *tiltul min hatzad*, does the need to save the bread override the prohibition of muktzah?

Comment: Also, you may want to direct your attention to the sugyas of *hidbik pas batanur* (Shabbos, 4a; see also Ritva ad loc) and *shachach pas batanur* (Shabbos, 117b), which may have bearing on this topic. For example, was the baking retrospectively assur? If so, should one (a.) remove the dough before the crust hardens, thus preempting a possible issur, (b.) wait until it is fully cooked, or (c.) leave it to burn?

Comment: The case is where you kneaded (kned?) the dough before Yom Tov? If so, wasn't it muktza already as soon as Yom Tov started? What do you mean by 'become'?

Comment: @fred u summed it up very nicley,but #3 not sure about.

Comment: @DoubleAA the person did not realize the whole time until it was in the oven.

Comment: There's another issue: You cannot burn challah on Yom Tov ([Shabbos 24b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=24b&format=pdf); Rashi, [Pesachim 46a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=46&format=pdf)).

Comment: Why in Eretz Yisrael? There's a chiyuv to separate challah in chutz la'aretz as well.

Comment: @ShimonbM In Chu"l one can eat the bread and leave a piece over as Challah at the end. So the loaf is definitely not muktza before separating.

Comment: Thanks, @DoubleAA, I didn't know that - nor enough to be able to answer this question, though I'm pretty sure you're not allowed to burn qodshim on yontef (is challah qodesh?). There's a discussion in Pesachim somewhere that might be informative. The relevant mishna is 3:3, which discusses separating impure challah on yontef Pesach. Not exactly the same question that is being asked here, but it might be relevant to a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what the Ramah writes in SA Siman 457:1 and SA Horav #16), there is a way to take Challa on Yom Tov: you could make a new dough (make the size of one Challah, because your going to have to eat that bread on that same day, per Mogen Avraham 506:11) bake it and AFTERWARD do צירוף כלי (put the Erev YT breads and the new bread in one utensil) and remove Challah from the NEW bread.

Comment: Right, but for the rama is it muktza until then? Also, why do you need tzeiruf kli?

Comment: BTW when I saw this pop up on the front page this morning, I said: I better get myself together and post the stuff I've found or Meir Zirkind will probably get there first.

Comment: Also your last point (while fascinating!) is not relevant here. We only give challat chu"l to young kohanim, not challah from Israel.

Comment: It wouldn't be Muktza just like the dough that's kneaded on YT is not Muktza before removing Challah. The reason you need Tziruf Keli is because if one of the doughs is less than the Shiur it needs Tziruf to be Cayyav on Challah. When I found the Chasam Sofer (quoted in Daas Torah 506:2 I was too excited about it to remember to look into that detail, but anyway I was half right because the Tur YD 322 says according to the Rosh it can be given to a Katan in EY as well but the Rambam says it can't. But Lehalacha you're right so I'll take that out.

Comment: How could our case be with less than a shiur of dough? The new dough needs a shiur (see Mishna Berura 26), and the old one wouldn't be otherwise chayav if it didn't have a shiur?

Comment: Anyway, regarding your main point about muktza: that's the same psak I saw in shemirat shabbat kehilchata based on the rama you quoted. I was waiting to post while trying to decipher some mysterious footnotes of his which seem to say a tosfos thinks that it really should be muktza and leaves it in a tazrich iyun.

Comment: About the Shiur of dough, I know it's a Machlokes Achronim and that's why I wrote based on SA Horav because he holds you don't need Shiur Challah. According to those who require Shiur Challah you could do it to but you've got to eat that entire batch on YT and that's not always easy.

Comment: There is also another point in this story, if he leaves the bread in the oven that means he baked on YT for nothing which Min HaTorah is a Melacha. There are also Rishonim who hold one may take Challah on YT from a dough that was made on Erev YT, and therefore the Halocho is that Bdi'ovad if one took Challah he may eat it, so in this case -Sha'as Hadchak which is treated as Bdi'ovad- maybe a Rav will allow him to take Challah not to transgress a Melacha.

Answer (score 1):

*I wrote the bulk of this immediately after the question was posted several months ago, but I decided not to post it as it is sort of a long comment rather than a definitive answer. After I was reminded of this question by a [recent post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28465), I decided I might as well post my comments here. CYLOR, as usual.*

If someone kneaded dough on Yom Tov of Pesach, and it became tamei, the opinion of Rabbi Eliezer in the Mishna (*P'sachim* 46a) is that the dough should be baked before challah is separated so that the challah doesn't turn into chametz. R' Eliezer holds that this is not *afiya shelo l'tzorech* prior to the separation of challah. Rabbeinu Baruch writes that the challah is muktza only after it is separated, since it is not fitting to be eaten in its state of tumah ([*Sefer HaT'ruma*, *Hil. Challah*, § 84](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8917&st=&pgnum=38)).

This seems to imply that, *binidon didan*, the fact that challah has not yet been separated does not intrinsically make the bread muktza. The question remains whether the bread is muktza because it may not be eaten on Yom Tov. Seemingly, the bread would be muktza because it would not be considered a *davar shenigmar bidei adam* since it cannot be made edible until after yom tov (so we can expect that *asach da'tei minaihu*) (*Mishna B'rura*, 310:19).

The bread seemingly may not be baked because, in this case, it would seem to be *afiya shelo l'tzorech*, as it may not be eaten on Yom Tov. Additionally, it seems that it may not be left to burn because of you cannot burn challah on Yom Tov (*Shabbos* 24b; *Rashi*, *P'sachim* 46a).

Assuming one could not apply the solution described in [Meir Zirkind's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28100), it would seem that the bread would need to be removed from the oven *kil'achar yad*. However, it may be logistically difficult to remove bread from a hot oven *kil'achar yad*; ironically, R' Moshe Feinstein is quoted as saying that it is questionable whether even moving an item backhanded qualifies as *kil'achar yad* (*Igros Moshe* OC vol. 5, 22:8).

It is further questionable whether one would be allowed to remove the bread in a normal manner, thus violating the *d'rabbanan* of muktza, in order to avoid cooking the bread, which would constitute a biblical prohibition. This seems to be related to the topic explored in the *sugya* of *hidbik pas batanur* (*Shabbos* 4a; see [here](http://divreichaim.blogspot.com/2006/04/does-avoiding-issur-doraysa-license.html) and [here](http://divreichaim.blogspot.com/2006/04/violating-derabbanan-to-avoid-doraysa.html) for some discussion of relevant points).

Answer (score 0):

Being that you are allowed to bake bread on Yom Tov, it would follow that you are allowed to do anything you can to eat the bread, including taking off challah, (because without taking off challah the bread is tevel). This is provable from Pesachim 36b/37a: "...Beis Hillel permit the baking of 'pas aveh' on yom tov... what is 'pas aveh'? 'pas merubeh'", i.e. a lot of bread, implying even an amount that would be chayav in challah. It would therefore follow that the bread is not muktzeh, being that is is indeed usable- all you need to do is take challah. (For more information on taking challah on Yom Tov, see Pesachim 46a/b.)

Comment: You can only take Challah if the dough was kneaded on Yom Tov, hence my caveat in the question that it was kneaded before Yom Tov, see OC 506:3.

Comment: We pasken that if you kneaded the dough before Yom Tov, yet you neglected to separate challah before Yom Tov, you may not separate it on Yom Tov. Further, in Eretz Yisrael, you may not eat from it until the challah is separated.

Comment: Thank you guys for clarifying this.case that is what I meant before yom tov.